# excel database function in combination with vba, what if there are no records?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the database function of excel. see example image

[image]

I use vba to select records that have 'yes' for lets say A

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="yes"
Range("B3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

I then copy it to paste it somewhere else. for example:

```
Selection.Copy
Range("B12").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

The problem is that when there are no records with yes, i get error 1004. Probably because there is nothing to paste. How do I write a script so that if there is nothing to paste, it exits the sub?

I tried things like counta but to no succes.

Your help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like doing it this way because you don't need to error check it. If there are no results, it will simply paste a blank cell:

```
Sub tgr()

    With Range("B2").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter 2, "yes"
        Intersect(.Offset(1), Columns("B")).Copy Range("B12")
        .AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

Alternately, if you only have one criteria, you could use Countif to test if the criteria exists before performing the filter:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim strCriteria As String

    strCriteria = "yes"

    With Range("B2").CurrentRegion
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Intersect(.Cells, Columns("C")), strCriteria) > 0 Then
            .AutoFilter 2, strCriteria
            Intersect(.Offset(1), Columns("B")).Copy Range("B12")
            .AutoFilter
        Else
            MsgBox "No cells found to contain """ & strCriteria & """", , "No Matches"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works perfectly. Also like the fact that there is an 'else' option for msgbox or something else. Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This will check the number of visible cells after the AutoFilter is applied:

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="yes"
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns.Count > 0 Then
    Range("B3").Select
    Range(Range("b3"), Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

The `- ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns.Count` part is to subtract the header cells from the count.

FWIW, when I walked through your original code, I got the 1004 because the Copy area was from B7 to the bottom of the sheet (the effect of xlDown in an empty selection).

Comment: Thanks Joe for your reply. I copied your script to a macro, but I still get the 1004 error if there are no records with the value yes. Am I missing something?

Comment: If there's no values being displayed, it shouldn't get past the If statement at all.  Are you trying it with exactly the same values as your example?

Comment: yes. Could it have something to do with the fact that we're using excel 2003 here at work?

Comment: No, it was a bug in my code.  I've corrected it above.  The ".End" should have started from B2, not Selection.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUBTOTAL worksheet function to count the visible rows and only do the copy and paste if there are visible rows.  Here's an example.

```
Sub CopyFiltered()

    Dim rToFilter As Range
    Dim rToCopy As Range
    Dim rToPaste As Range

    Set rToFilter = Selection
    Set rToPaste = rToFilter.Cells(1).Offset(10, 0) 'paste it 10 rows down

    rToFilter.AutoFilter 2, "yes"

    'Use subototal to count the visible rows in column 1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, rToFilter.Columns(1)) > 0 Then
        'Copy excluding the header row
        Set rToCopy = rToFilter.Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rToFilter.Rows.Count - 1)
        rToCopy.Copy Destination:=rToPaste
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But for some reason it doesn't copy the values if there are records with the value yes. I'm using excel 2003 here at work. I'll try it at home aswell.